# How can I complete my tests on Akka flow?

Tags: scala, testing, akka, akka-stream

I am getting an error that says "Error running FlowTests: Test name not found"

I have been following the examples on Akka's documentation website, but they don't seem to work

Here is my code for the test:

```
class FlowTests extends TestKit(ActorSystemContainer.getInstance().getSystem) {

  val usersDataLines = scala.io.Source.fromFile("data/BX-Users-TEST.csv", "ISO-8859-1").getLines().drop(1)
  val usersSource = Source.fromIterator(() => usersDataLines)

  usersSource.runWith(TestSink.probe[String]).expectNext("some data").expectComplete()
}
```

Comment: I think you need to use some test framework like ScalaTest for your tests to be runnable, but I'm not 100% sure. Also, instead of `scala.io.Source` consider using native methods for disk I/O from [FileIO](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/#akka.stream.scaladsl.FileIO$); most likely, they would give you more correct and performant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I figured it out.  I was using the FlowTest class as a Scala test however what I needed to do is create a class that extends FunSuite and from there call my FlowTests with awaitAssert()